# Has this group something to do with the cone of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Consider the group $V=(-1,1)$ with addition $+_{rel}:V\times V\to V$ defined as:

$$v+_{rel}w=\frac{v+w}{1+vw}$$

This group is analogous to the relativistic velocities where the speed of light equals $1$ or $-1$.

What I've noticed is that if we consider the set $[-1,1]$ instead of $(-1,1)$ with the same addition formula then it is no longer a group, because $1+_{rel}(-1)$ is not defined, as $1+1(-1)=1-1=0$. What is more interesting, is that if we take the sets $[-1,1)$ or $(-1,1]$ then it is a group, telling us that, in my opinion, the speed of light can only take one direction, and there is nothing going at "negative the speed of light", even if we define $c=-1$. I find this analogous to the cone of light, where, even if there is half the cone there, light chooses to go just one direction, and cannot go both. So, my question is what is the connection between this group and the cone of light, if anything.

Comment: Clearly light _can_ go in any direction in any frame of reference.

Comment: BTW, $\frac0 0$ isn't exactly undefined, it's an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: If you take $(-1,1]$, then what is the inverse of $1$ in this group?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, taking the half-open or half-closed interval breaks the group structure. For example, the end point that you’ve added (either +1 or -1) does not have an inverse in the group. So that is a flaw in the premise of the question.

Beyond this error, I’m not aware of any useful connection between the group and the light cone beyond the obvious connection that you made that the operation you’ve chosen is the relativistic velocity addition formula, which we know is compatible with the limitation that no boost can transform a frame of reference to one with relative velocity equal to the speed of light.